# JSON no longer parsable after being sent through TCP in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, tcp

I've created a basic client and server that pass a string, which I've changed to JSON instead. But the JSON string is only parsable before it gets sent through TCP. After it's sent, the string version is identical (after a chomp), but on the server side it no longer processes the JSON correctly. Here is some of my code (with other bits trimmed)

Some of the client code

```
require 'json'
require 'socket'

foo = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3}

puts foo.to_s + "......."

foo.to_json
puts foo['b'] # => outputs the correct '2' answer

client = TCPSocket.open('localhost', 2000)
client.puts json
client.close;
```

Some of the server code

```
require 'socket'
require 'json'
server = TCPServer.open(2000)

while true

  client = server.accept # Accept client
  response = client.gets

  print response
  response = response.chomp
  response.to_json

  puts response['b'] # => outputs 'b'

end
```

The output 'b' should be '2' instead. How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In your server you wrote `response.to_json`. This turns a string to JSON, then throws it away. And I don't like the `.chomp`, either.

Try

```
response = client.gets
hash = JSON.parse(response)
```

Now `hash` is a Ruby Hash object with your data in it, and `hash['b']` should work correctly.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because of the line 'hash = JSON.parse(response)'. It crashes the server. It stops output like "puts 'abc' " for example. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.to_json` does not parse JSON inside a string and replace itself with the result. It is used to convert the string into a format that is an acceptable JSON value.

```
require 'json'
string = "abc"
puts string
puts string.to_json
```

This will output:

```
abc
"abc"
```

The method is added to the `String` class by the JSON generator and it uses it internally to generate the JSON document.

But why does your `response['b']` return `"b"`?

Because Ruby strings have a method called `[]` that can be used to:

- Return a substring: `"abc"[0,2] => "ab"`
- Return a single character from index: `"abc"[1] => "b"`
- Return a substring if the string contains it: `"abc"["bc"] => "bc"`, `"abc"["fg"] => nil`
- Return a regexp match: `"abc"[/^a([a-z])c/, 1] => "b"`
- and possibly some other ways I can't think of right now.

So this happens because your response is a string that has the character "b" in it:

```
response = "something with a b"
puts response["b"]
# outputs b
puts response["x"]
# outputs a blank line because response does not contain "x".
```

Instead of `.to_json` your code has to call `JSON.parse` or `JSON.load`:

```
data = JSON.parse(response)
puts data['b']
```

Comment: for safety reasons I would recommend `JSON::parse` over `JSON::load`